# Suggest ways to encourage curiosity in maths through memes

Tags: soft-question, education

In one of our informal math research club sessions we are thinking of hosting a math meme making competition. Our idea is that math memes will trigger curiosity and interest among the participants. This would not only help in questioning and understanding the mathematical ideas behind the meme but the participants will also have fun doing it. Lets say that I go ahead with this idea. What could be a possible way achieve best results?

Comment: Sometimes the memes are too high level to be understood…

Comment: Yes I agree. So we have thought of asking the participants to add a short explanation or links to the same.  As you rightly pointed out, we must also make sure that the ideas are not incomprehensible for a general math student.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was always attracted to formal seminars : humble and great professors bringing their work down to the general public using their excellent understanding of the concepts and techniques involved. I came into formal mathematics as a result of seeing inspiring applications of mathematics. Memes etc. have never been my cup of tea. Perhaps that makes me an outlier, but consider presenting recent papers in heavily applied mathematics and bringing them down to the level of a layman. That's more rewarding and inspiring, at least as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Have you got an example, Vasac, of a math meme that might trigger curiosity and interest, and/or help in understanding some mathematical ideas? Such an example might gives us some idea of just what it is that you are looking for.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I do. But I don't make very good memes myself. Here is a link  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUmiQ.jpg

Comment: Maths Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum: please check out the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). As such, questions asking for other people's opinions should not be asked here.

Comment: @TobyMak The question has been edited

Comment: @Vasac Do you really think that meme will help someone understand the axiom of choice?

Comment: @JohnDouma No. But It will definitely grab attention and then make someone question.

Comment: @Vasac It will "definitely grab attention"? There really is no accounting for taste.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/mathmemes/

Answer (score 2):

Whatever interest is piqued will not be interest in math. For one, it is hard to imagine a math “meme” being both understandable to most people *and* about math in any meaningful way.

Second, math is not “memes”. Math is, at its core, puzzles. Many of these puzzles are beautiful or interesting. That is why math is worth studying. If you want people to become excited or engaged, show them the beauty and the intrigue.

Comment: But hasn't it ever happened to you that your curiosity in a mathematical concept arose from a meme. For instance I read about the Banach Tarski paradox first when I encountered a meme about it.

Comment: This has never happened to me. I think there is a danger to poorly communicating complicated ideas. Bad knowledge is worse than none at all. Math is complicated necessarily; any attempt to simplify or popularize it in that way comes at great cost.

Comment: While I am aware of the danger of a poor communication I also believe that one does not understand a topic well enough if one cannot explain it simply. And I find making a meme a very creative way of doing it. To filter out poor communications have a panel of experts who will scrutinize them thoroughly before they are presented.

Comment: That is a silly and too popular idea. Some ideas *are complicated* and there can be no simple explanation that does not lose something. In addition, “memes” aren’t a good format for conveying simple information either. I don’t see what the point of any of this is.

Comment: If that is so then atleast this can be an engaging start for something that requires more rigor.

Comment: How is it engaging? Show them the beauty and the intrigue. The example with Banach Tarski, did that interest you because it was a meme, or because it was fascinating? Again, what is the advantage of memes over anything else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147630/discussion-between-malady-and-vasac).

Comment: How about this. Imagine you understand the concept (Say BT paradox). You want to present it to an audience.  But I tell u that Ill give you very little time(say 2-3 mins) to convey a gist of your idea and after that if people are interested they may meet you personally and discuss. In such a situation I think presenting a meme along will a short explanation is also a good idea just like solving some puzzle is.  And come on don't tell me that people in general don't like memes or don't find it engaging. You can only make something funny if you know it well.

Comment: @Vasac I know that your question isn't meant for me, but personally, under that kind of constraint, I simply wouldn't bother making the attempt in the first place. To paraphrase Malady, there are concepts that cannot be simplified without comprimising the very concept you're trying to communicate, and if somebody asks you to explain such a concept in such a short timeframe, then they're basically setting you up to fail (and the audience, assuming they want genuinely accurate information). Why engage in a futile endeavour like that?

Comment: Sometimes a little compromising might be necessary to get things started. This must also be carefully rectified later.  This endeavour need not be futile and I believe Michael Stevens (VSauce) is one of the examples.